# show alert after audio playing specific time

Tags: javascript, audio

I want to show an alert after ten seconds playing audio.

```
<audio id="player01" controls src="01.mp3" ontimeupdate="test()"></audio>
```

js

```
var player01 = document.getElementById("player01");

function test(){
    if (player01.currentTime == 10) {
        alert (10);
    }
};
```

Alert doesn't appear. Console is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use the `ontimeupdate` event:

```
var player01 = document.getElementById("player01");

player01.ontimeupdate = function() {
    if (parseInt(this.currentTime) == 10) {
        alert (10);
    }
};
```

Reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_timeupdate.asp

Comment: ok, that was due to currentTime not returning an integer. I have updated the code to parse that number into an integer.

Comment: You might want to unbind that event when that conditional statement resolves to true the first time, otherwise that code will run multiple times.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now. Could you maybe explain why my code doesn't work. What is the purpose of `ontimeupdate="..."` inside html code at all ?

Comment: You're welcome. I suspect it might have to do with comparing a float with an integer - you might want to log your .currentTime outside your if statement to see whether it is returning the current time. It might also have to do with whether you element already existed by the time you defined player01.